# Is this sentence grammatically correct? - Two verbs in a main clause

Tags: meaning, verbs

> It will not be directly apparent a virus exists while it is memory resident.

This came from a description of a computer virus in the Microsoft website, but I cannot understand the structure since there are two verbs (be and exists) in the main clause.
Referring to the google translation, I think it would likely mean...

> The fact that a virus exists while it is memory resident will not be directly apparent.

I still don't understand why the main clause should have the two verbs and if that is really grammatically correct. Could somebody explain in detail?

Comment: This is a case of _that omission_: _It will not be directly apparent **[that]** a virus exists._

Comment: In my opinion your rephrasing changes the meaning.

Comment: @fev What's with this bizarre fear of using *that* sweeping the land? Strange.

Comment: @tchrist Economy of language maybe? But I wouldn't compromise the lack of ambiguity for the sake of being economic... I don't get it either.

Comment: It's certainly not a good sentence: the scope of the *while* clause isn't immediately obvious. Compare "It is not widely believed a woman is happy while she is unmarried", which probably has the opposite scope.

Answer (score 2):

Matrix clauses contain two or more verbs typically occurring in one or more embedded subordinate clauses.

Here, the matrix clause (the whole sentence) contains a number of subordinate clauses.

The detailed clause bracketing is:

> [*It will* [*not be directly apparent* [*a virus exists while* [*it is
> memory* *resident*]]]].

From this, we can see that the matrix clause (in outer brackets) contains three embedded subordinate clauses.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct. You have an “anticipatory *it*” standing in as a dummy subject for the true subject, which appears later in the sentence.

Your true subject is a “zero *that*” *that*-clause. Here is your sentence showing the *that* of the *that*-clause:

> *It will not be directly apparent [that] a virus exists while it is memory resident.*

Here it is with the true subject at the beginning:

> *That a virus exists will not be directly apparent while it is memory resident.*

Adding *the fact* in front (*The fact that a virus exists . . .*) makes the *that*-clause an appositive, but the meaning is the same with or without *the fact*.

<sub>Further reading on *zero that* and extraposition with *that*-clauses: [ThoughtCo: ’That’-Clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/that-clause-definition-1692539)</sub>